# Calculating Pearson correlation coefficients without cor()

Tags: r

How do I calculate Pearson correlation coefficients manually, without using the `cor()` function?

Comment: The Pearson correlation coefficient formula is: r = (n*sumXY - sumX*sum Y)/sqrt{(n*sumX^2 - (sumX)^2)*(n*sumY^2 - (sumY^2))}. Just put it inside a function call.

Answer (score 0):

I will rather approach an example based approach that should help you.

```
# Sample data
X <- 1:10
Y <- 11:20

# Step 1 
## Calculate the mean for both these variables
meanX <- mean(X)
meanY <- mean(Y)

# Step 2
## Now, you need to calculate the deviation of each vector element 
## from this vector's respective mean for both these variables
devX <- X - meanX
devY <- Y - meanY

# Step 3
## Next, we need to multiply the deviations for each elements for both variables 
prodDev <- devX * devY

# Step 4
## Now, we need to add up the above (step 3) products to get the numerator
numerator <- sum(prodDev)

# Step 5
## Similary, calculate the standard deviation for both these variables, as given below
sX <- sqrt(sum((X - meanX)^2) / (length(X) - 1))
sY <- sqrt(sum((Y - meanY)^2) / (length(Y) - 1))

# Step 6
## And, multiply the standard deviations for both these variables
prodS <- sX * sY

# Finally: 
## We divide the numerator by the product of the standard deviations to get the Pearson correlation coefficient 'r' as follows
r <- numerator / prodS

# Print the correlation coefficient
r
```

Let me know if this helps..